# IOS objective c calendar fail to compare the dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, calendar

i have a set of date that has a format as 2015-11-09T01:00:30.31. I want to compare just the year month and day only. Therefore i use calendar function to compare it if current day is equal to the dates in the nsarray.

here is my codes:

```
   NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new]; // to create the dates in the for loop
    df.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
 NSDate *now = [calender dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:0 toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

 NSDate *oneDaysAgo = [calender dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:-1 toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];



    for (NSDictionary *feed in feeds) {
        if ([feed[@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Warning"] )  {

            NSDate *updateTimestampGMT = [df dateFromString:feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"]];
            if ([calender isDate:updateTimestampGMT inSameDayAsDate:now]) {
                warningCount++;
            }

        }
        else if([feed[@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Informational"])  {
            NSDate *updateTimestampGMT = [df dateFromString:feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"]];
            if ([calender isDate:updateTimestampGMT inSameDayAsDate:now]) {
                informationCount++;
            }

        }

        else if([feed[@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Critical"])  {
            NSDate *updateTimestampGMT = [df dateFromString:feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"]];
            if ([calender isDate:updateTimestampGMT inSameDayAsDate:now]) {
                criticalCount++;
            }

        }
        else if([feed[@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Emergency"])  {
            NSDate *updateTimestampGMT = [df dateFromString:feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"]];
            if ([calender isDate:updateTimestampGMT inSameDayAsDate:now]) {
                emergencyCount++;
            }

        }




    }

    for (NSDictionary *feed in feeds) {
      if ([feed[@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Warning"] ) {
            NSDate *updateTimestampGMT = [df dateFromString:feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"]];
            if ([calender isDate:updateTimestampGMT inSameDayAsDate:oneDaysAgo]) {
                minusOneDaywarningCount++;
            }
        }

          else if([feed[@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Informational"])  {

            NSDate *updateTimestampGMT = [df dateFromString:feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"]];
            if ([calender isDate:updateTimestampGMT inSameDayAsDate:oneDaysAgo]) {
                minusOneDayinformationCount++;

            }


        }

        else if([feed[@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Critical"]) {
            NSDate *updateTimestampGMT = [df dateFromString:feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"]];
            if ([calender isDate:updateTimestampGMT inSameDayAsDate:oneDaysAgo]) {
                minusOneDaycriticalCount++;

            }

        }
         else if([feed[@"Severity"] isEqualToString:@"Emergency"]){

            NSDate *updateTimestampGMT = [df dateFromString:feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"]];
            if ([calender isDate:updateTimestampGMT inSameDayAsDate:oneDaysAgo]) {
                minusOneDayemergencyCount++;
            }


        }



    }
```

when i run the codes. There is this error. please help me solve it. i really need to compare the dates only not the time.

Here is the error:

```
 *** -[NSCalendar isDate:inSameDayAsDate:]: date1 cannot be nil
Future exception.
A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply be ignored.
Here is the backtrace where this occurred this time (some frames may be missing due to compiler optimizations):
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001830029b4 <redacted> + 100
    1   FYP_IOS_APP                         0x00000001000648bc -[IncidentFequencyViewController parserDidEndDocument:] + 12844
    2   libxml2.2.dylib                     0x0000000198b04058 xmlParseChunk + 1248
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000183f38cdc <redacted> + 44
    4   Foundation                          0x0000000183f38e40 <redacted> + 328
    5   FYP_IOS_APP                         0x0000000100060e70 -[IncidentFequencyViewController connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 376
    6   CFNetwork                           0x000000018287f6a8 <redacted> + 80
    7   CFNetwork                           0x000000018287f638 <redacted> + 200
    8   CFNetwork                           0x000000018287f7ac <redacted> + 56
    9   CFNetwork                           0x00000001826eb4fc <redacted> + 100
    10  CFNetwork                           0x00000001827d9b38 <redacted> + 108
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001001a9c68 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001001b340c _dispatch_block_invoke + 564
    13  CFNetwork                           0x00000001826d7ce4 <redacted> + 36
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182ed06cc CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    15  CFNetwork                           0x00000001826d7bc8 <redacted> + 136
    16  CFNetwork                           0x00000001826d7a88 <redacted> + 312
    17  CFNetwork                           0x00000001826d78b4 <redacted> + 68
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182fa4544 <redacted> + 24
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182fa3fd8 <redacted> + 540
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182fa1cd8 <redacted> + 724
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182ed0ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018e454088 GSEventRunModal + 180
    23  UIKit                               0x00000001885e8ffc UIApplicationMain + 204
    24  FYP_IOS_APP                         0x00000001000758e4 main + 124
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000198cda8b8 <redacted> + 4
)
```

Comment: check the date on here **NSDate *now**, in here you get nil value check once

Comment: Why is `NSDate *now = [calender dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:0 toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];` not written as `NSDate *now = [NSDate date]`?

Comment: because it give the time as well when u print it out.. i just want to compare the date only not the time.

Comment: I don't think you understand how date handling works.  Your code gives you exactly the same thing as `[NSDate date]`, because you're telling the calendar instance to do nothing to it.

Comment: In terms of your bug, I would check that `feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"]` has what you think in it.

Comment: so how would you code in order to match the dates?

Comment: feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"] contains dates in this format 2015-11-06T01:02:54

Comment: i just want to compare the year month and day in feed[@"UpdateTimestampGMT"] , how to do it?